# Using let and const in short lived variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have a short lived variable that the GC will clean up pretty quickly, something like:

```
function doSomeThing() {
  var someValue = someCalculation();
  return someValue;
}
```

Now assume that `someCalculation()` is actually a placeholder for something that requires its return value to be set to a variable, or maybe something in react like:

```
render() {
  var someComponent = someValues.map(someComponentFactory());
  return (
    <div>    
      <someComponent />
    </div>
  )
}
```

In both cases `someComponent` and `someValue` are short lived variables that will be cleaned up once the function returns.

What's the right approach when using `let` and `const`?

`const` makes sense because the value won't change, but `let` makes sense because you're not really setting a 'constant' value, it gets thrown away immediately.

I've tried to find something in the way the javascript engine works or some performance reason you'd use one or the other but I can't find anything.

So the question is, when declaring a immediately thrown away variable should you use `let` or `const`?

Comment: There is no "right" answer to this, it's entirely subjective.

Comment: @loganfsmyth that's my worry, I was hoping for a 'js sets mem aside for a const so let is better' kind of an anwser but i expect it's just style/opinion on which is best

Comment: I think I'd go for `const`, because it means that you can't reassign the value. Other than that `const` allows optimizations that increase efficiency, because the compiler knows the variable won't be updated (ie. caller, take this reference, I'm not going to use it anymore anyway). In the end javascript-code gets compiled; I wouldn't worry about performance here.

Comment: @Caramiriel Sure about the optimization part? `const` variables can still be mutated, so I wouldn't be too sure...

Comment: @le_m: the contents can be edited, but the reference can't. :)

Comment: *"I was hoping for a 'js sets mem aside for a const so let is better' kind of an anwser"* How implementations allocate memory for bindings is ... implementation dependent. So, in general, this is subjective. You could look at the implementation of a specific engine though.

Comment: I'd say it doesn't matter at all, Even using `var` in a function scope like that would be the same as either `let` or `const`, and the performance difference would be microscopic, if any at all, and as for style, that's subjective.

Comment: @Caramiriel But static analysis in the compiler can determine if a `let` is reassigned in all cases excluding `with` and `eval` too, so `const` vs `let` is mostly useful for developers rather than engines.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: I agree.

Comment: It is a matter of taste. It is up to you and your style guide if `const` is used for real constants or all variables that shouldn't be reassigned. It is 2 extra chars vs extra safeguard, and bugs caused by accidental reassignments are very rare IME. In both cases real constants may still use *CONSTANT* naming convention. Check also [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6).

Comment: Why exactly, do you think, does the life span of a variable make any difference?

Comment: @zeroflagL because I'd expect the internals to treat it differently, something like in a language that makes you declare an arrays length (rather then dynamically sized) so it can assign fixed memory for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `const` will not allow you to "help" garbage collection. Sometimes a pattern developers follow is to unset a variable to signal that the variable is ready to be garbage collected.

For example:

```
function doSomeThing() {
    let someValue = someCalculation();
    // pass off to another function
    anotherFunction(someValue);
    someValue = null;
}
```

If you were using `const`, you could not reassign `someValue` to `null`. However, when no more active code has reference to this, it will be garbage collected anyways which falls back to what you wrote originally. So the unsetting is really the only difference.

Here's a little snippet on the subject from [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md):

> Warning: Assigning an object or array as a constant means that value will not be able to be garbage collected until that constant's lexical scope goes away, as the reference to the value can never be unset. That may be desirable, but be careful if it's not your intent!

Comment: Just to clarify here... the `someValue = null` in this case will make no difference, because the scope of `doSomeThing()` is about to be destroyed anyway. The pattern of setting to `null` of a variable -- which is what I was referring to in the quoted note from my book -- is done to let the value it referenced (like an object or array) be earlier eligible for GC than when the parent scope goes away, in cases where the scope is going to stay around a long while (usually because of closure) but we're done with the value.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `const`. For me, `let` is used to signal that you are creating a variable that is going to be changed. I never use it unless I have a good reason for creating such a variable.

For everything else, use `const`.